# Null pointer argument in call to CFRelease

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I cannot seem to structure this method so that when I analyse the project it doesn't complain.

It is complaining about how I release people object.

```
- (NSArray *)getAllContacts {

    NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);

    CFRelease(addressBook);

    NSArray *peopleArray = (NSArray *)people;

    //  Return if there are no contacts in the address book
    if (peopleArray && peopleArray.count > 0) {

        for (int i = 0; i <= peopleArray.count -1; i++) {

            ABRecordRef person = [peopleArray objectAtIndex:i];
            ABRecordID sourceID = ABRecordGetRecordID(person);

            TableViewControllerItem *item = [AddressBookModel createTableViewControllerItemFromABRecordID:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", sourceID]];
            [result addObject:item];
        }
        CFRelease(people); //If I put the release here I get a potential leak of people
    }

    CFRelease(people); //If I put the release here I get a null pointer argument in call to CFRelease

    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
// Remove the CFRelease() inside the if-block
```

And modify the *CFRelease()* before the *return* statement to be like this,

```
if (peopleArray) CFRelease(people);
return [NSArray arrayWithArray:result];
```